# How to send passwords using https?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, https

> Facebook currently uses HTTPS whenever your password is sent to us

So when I go to http://www.facebook.com and click login, they have sent my username and password through https even though I am not on a https connection yet.

Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: Well, it works by establishing an HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form's action is `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1`.  The page with the login form doesn't need to be https, as it is just used to craft a request to the https page.

Also, since http is stateless, you're not really "on" a connection until the moment you send a request.  After you get a response, and the page draws, you are no longer "on" the connection.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a form just post it to a https page.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="https://mypage.com" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="mytext" />
      <input type="submit />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should work even though you are not a https secured page.